# Recovering deleted Toolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arccatalog, toolbox

While working, I accidentally deleted a toolbox where I had very important processes. I went to the recycle bin but couldn't find it.

[image]

Is it possible to recover it?

Comment: Unless it was on a network that allows restores then I think the short answer is no.

Comment: Toolboxes should be on your local or network drive. Have you tried a Windows  File Explorer search for "Wildfiretools.tbx"? If you find where it lives, you can then just right click on Toolboxes and select Add Toolbox and you can re-add it.